# render table via reactjs keep showing no matching records found

Tags: node.js, reactjs, bootstrap-table

I'm using bootrap-table from http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/.
I'm using reactjs to render the table after searching for data, the problem is although the table have data on it, it's still showing that "no matching 
 records found". Please help me, thank you.
This is my react code for render table:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

class Form extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.props.submitData}>
                <h2 className="card-inside-title">Floating Label Examples</h2>
                <div className="row clearfix">
                    <div className="col-sm-12">
                        <div className="form-group form-float form-group-lg">
                            <div className="form-line">
                                <input type="text" className="form-control" name="stockNumber" autoFocus
                                       onChange={this.props.inputChange}/>
                                <label className="form-label">Stock number</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group form-float form-group-lg">
                            <div className="form-line">
                                <input type="text" className="form-control" name="personalPassportId"
                                       onChange={this.props.inputChange}/>
                                <label className="form-label">Personal ID/Passport number</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group form-float form-group-lg">
                            <div className="form-line">
                                <input type="text" className="form-control" name="name"
                                       onChange={this.props.inputChange}/>
                                <label className="form-label">Stockholder name</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row clearfix">
                    <div className="col-sm-12">
                        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-lg btn-primary waves-effect">
                            Submit
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        )
    }
}

class Rows extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <tr>
                <td>{this.props.rowData.stocknumber}</td>
                <td>{this.props.rowData.personalpassportid}</td>
                <td>{this.props.rowData.name}</td>
            </tr>
        )
    }
}

class Table extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            rowsData: []
        };
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        this.setState({
            rowsData: nextProps.tableData
        });
    }

    render() {
        var rows = [];
        this.state.rowsData.forEach((rowsData) => {
            rows.push(<Rows rowData={rowsData} key={rowsData.id}/>)
        });
        return (
            <table data-toggle="table">
                <thead className="bg-deep-orange">
                <tr>
                    <th>Stock Number</th>
                    <th>Personal/Passport ID</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>{rows}</tbody>
            </table>
        )
    }
}

class Content extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            stockNumber: '',
            personalPassportId: '',
            name: '',
            tableData: null
        };
        this.inputChange = this.inputChange.bind(this);
        this.submitData = this.submitData.bind(this)
    };

    inputChange(event) {
        const target = event.target;
        const value = target.value;
        const name = target.name;

        this.setState({
            [name]: value
        });
    };

    submitData(event) {
        const {stockNumber, personalPassportId, name} = this.state;

        axios.post('/attend', {
            stockNumber: stockNumber,
            personalPassportId: personalPassportId,
            name: name
        }).then((response) => {
            this.setState({
                tableData: response.data
            });
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });

        event.preventDefault();
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Form inputChange={this.inputChange} submitData={this.submitData}/>
                <div className="row clearfix">
                    <div className="col-sm-12">
                        <Table tableData={this.state.tableData}/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Content/>, document.getElementById('content'));
```

[Table keep showing "No matching records found"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8U9s.png)

Comment: from where is the message coming "No matching records found" ?

Comment: @JonahPereira It's a default message when there is no data on table

Comment: Anyone please help :(